# Are html tables valid if there are multiple tbody tag used?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If there are multiple `<tbody>` tags in an HTML `<table>`, is this valid?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody
    <tbody>
    </tbody
</table>
```

Answer (score 22):

Yes, the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html) shows that it is allowed.

```
<!ELEMENT table
     (caption?, (col*|colgroup*), thead?, tfoot?, (tbody+|tr+))>
```

The DTD also has a comment which explains why:

> Use multiple tbody sections when rules
>   are needed between groups of table
>   rows.

Answer (score 5):

I copy pasted your title in google and the first link is : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3 ,

"Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or more table body sections",

so yes you can !

Answer (score 1):

Multiple table bodies is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have multiple `tbody`s in the same table.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Monday</td><td>#1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Friday</td><td>#2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Monday</td><td>#3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Friday</td><td>#4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```