# How to avoid rendering of defining tag in ng-repeat loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let's say that I have a simple loop like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.foo}}<br></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ui-view="itemView"></div>
```

How can I avoid rendering defining tag (`div`) to get:

```
Foo 1<br>
Foo 2<br>
Foo 3<br>
```

instead of:

```
<div>Foo 1<br></div>
<div>Foo 2<br></div>
<div>Foo 3<br></div>
```

**What for:** I need this i.e. to creating table rows where wrapping `<tr>` with `div` is not allowed, YES I know that I can use `<tr ng-repeat=...` for simple cases, anyway I'd prefer to move rendering `tr` tag into `itemView` as well (I have several conditions to check for adding i.e. proper CSS classes, otherwise I'll need to add these classes into each `td` in row)

Comment: Why not an ul instead? This is allowed inside table, and you can avoid the awkward <br> tag. I never saw a default behavior of ng-repeat without an element. You can create a custom directive to override the div as well

Comment: @Fals `br` is just a sample, `tr` is my current case (and maybe `ul` will help - need to check, but I'd really would be happy to get possibility of avoiding wrapping it with nesting tag especially when using dedicated views via ui-view. Can you point me how to create custom directive for this simple scenario ? (of course as an answer so guys can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating custom directive with ***replace: true*** attribute you can replace the original html div with the directive's template

here is an example inspired from the ng-book:

```
<div my-directive></div>

app.directive('myDirective' function() {
    return {
        template: '<div>my directive without replacement</div>
    }
});
```

the html will keep the  and inject inside it the directive's template like:

```
<div my-directive>
    <div>my directive without replacement</div>
</div>
```

But if you set "replace: true" like:

```
app.directive('myDirective' function() {
    return {
        replace: true
        template: '<div>my directive with replacement<div>'
    }
});
```

then there will be only the directive's template, which replaced the original

```
<div>my directive with replacement<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody):

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.foo }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is useful and I'll keep in mind for other scenarios with tables (TBH I was sure that table can contain only one `tbody` but spec allows for repeating it.

Comment: @biesior you can have multiple tbody in one table, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873701/are-html-tables-valid-if-there-are-multiple-tbody-tag-used